# open(1) in rifle.conf for ranger on OS X

Tags: terminal, osx, ranger

[ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org)

`~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf`

### For simplicity

What **one** line – in the rifle configuration file – could cause [open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)(1) to be used for **all** types of file?

#### Background

https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20080-post-111030.html#pid111030 under *Miller columns in file system explorers/browsers*.

*PC-BSD Forums* is, admittedly, not the best place for a question that overlaps with use, on OS X, of a command that first appeared in NextStep ;-) but this is – essentially – a plea for advice about a simple configuration for rifle.

My bookmarks about ranger include the following, one of which may include (or hint at) an answer but honestly, I'm half-lost. A pointer in the right direction might be all that's needed …

- [Official user guide · hut/ranger Wiki](https://github.com/hut/ranger/wiki/Official-user-guide)
- [Bloerg: Ranger File Manager](http://bloerg.net/2012/10/17/ranger-file-manager.html) (2012-10-17)
- [Installing and Using Ranger, a Terminal File Manager, on a Ubuntu VPS | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-and-using-ranger-a-terminal-file-manager-on-a-ubuntu-vps) (2013-07-12)
- [Ranger: speedy file management](http://nathantypanski.com/blog/2013-08-12-ranger.html) (2013-08-12, modified 2015-03-22)
- [Ubuntu Manpage: rifle - ranger's file opener](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/rifle.1.html)

#### OS X context

In edge cases (such as mine), for some areas of file systems, the operating system may be more responsive with ranger than with Finder. I have yet to ascertain whether a preference for ranger will reduce the need to use com.apple.IconServices …

---

### Presence of the file

In retrospect, after gaining an answer to this question, I realised that I had been overly cautious. In my history of commands –

```
gpes3e-gjp4:~ gjp22$ history | grep ranger\ --copy
  158  ranger --copy-config=commands
  169  ranger --copy-config=scope
```

– but not `ranger --copy-config=all`

I set aside `~/.config/ranger` and then ran that command to gain the default configuration file. Then added the overriding line that's given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223804/13260 below.

Still: the contents of the default file are foreign territory to me. With or without the lines and comments in that file, the '**one** line' essence of this question would have arisen.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the commands in [the first answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223552/13260) had the desired effect but based on those, I experimented with the following:

```
has open, flag f = open "$@"
```

Now, a `rifle.conf` file comprising just that one line does seem to be effective. If I understand correctly, the one and only condition, satisfied, is that `open` is installed (i.e. located in $PATH).

Google search results for [rifle.conf "has open"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rifle.conf%20%22has%20open%22) drew attention to https://github.com/rafi/.config/blob/master/ranger/rifle.conf

> ranger rifle open for osx, setting pass store dir

---

Following the first comment below I simplified the `rifle.conf` file to comprise:

```
flag f = open "$@"
```

That, too, seems to have the desired effect.

Comment: I don't know how `open` reacts to the `flag f` setting. It looks like from this example config that the `has open` setting is not required, so maybe something simpler like `flag f = open -- "$@"` or `flag t = open -- "$@"`

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

According to one of the ref links you posted, the line:

```
has open, flag f = open -a "$1"
```

or

```
has open, flag f = "open -a" "$1"
```

would be where I would start. I'm unable to test, not having access to OS X.

Comment: Thanks, which one of the links?

Comment: The Ubuntu man page link.

Comment: OK. I edited the question to explain that I had **not** run `ranger --copy-config=all`. Now, I see where you got the `has …` parts. Whilst neither of the lines in this answer were effective, you **do** win the bounty – for the attention, and for direction when I was "half-lost". Both lines *were* enough to get me thinking better. Thanks again. (Side note: that Ubuntu man page link `file://~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf` is not effective on OS X here.)